# Material implication in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic

I don't understand why in intuitionistic logic ¬P V Q entails P -> Q. I understand why classically are equivalent, but I don't get the entailment in intuitionistic logic.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why in intuitionistic logic ¬P V Q entails P -> Q

It is because `(¬P V Q) -> (P -> Q)` is *provable* from 
the axioms of intuitionistic propositional logic. There's nothing more to it.

If you still need convinced, consult one of the usual axiomizations (
e.g. [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)
or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic)) and prove
the theorem for yourself. It's a simple proof.

Comment: With all the respect, that's why I asked the question :) I am not sure how to prove it. Can you point me out which axioms from these http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#IntFirOrdPreLog are you using to do it?

Comment: Actually, this question is off-topic for SO because it is not about *programming*, and by rights should be closed! Move it to [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) if it keeps puzzling you or [request the moderators to move it there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/how-do-i-transfer-this-question-asked-on-stackoverflow-to-math-stackexchange-for).
With the axiom set you've linked,the proof needs Ax1, Ax8, Ax10 and modus ponens twice: 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
            ---------- (id)
            f, P |- f
------ (id) ---------- (Ex Falso)
P |- P      f, P |- Q
--------------------- (=>L)         --------- (id)
  (P => f), P |- Q                  Q, P |- Q
  ------------------------------------------- (vL)                              
         (P => f) v Q, P |- Q
         ---------------------- (=>R)
         (P => f) v Q |- P => Q
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof in Agda:

```
data ⊥ : Set where

⊥-elim : ∀ {w} {Whatever : Set w} → ⊥ → Whatever
⊥-elim ()

data Either (P Q : Set) : Set where
    Left : P → Either P Q
    Right : Q → Either P Q

material-implication : {P Q : Set} → Either (P → ⊥) Q → (P → Q)
material-implication (Left notp) p = ⊥-elim (notp p)
material-implication (Right q) p = q
```